# How to make JFrame paint only after I click button?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint

When I run the application the whole frame is painted black.

How can I make it so that it starts out clear then it gets painted when I press the button?

```
package card;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BdayCard extends JFrame {

JButton button1, button2;
JPanel panel;

BdayCard()
{
    panel = new JPanel();
    button1 = new JButton();

    button1.addActionListener( new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                repaint();
            }
    });

    panel.add(button1);

    this.add(panel);
    this.setTitle("It's Your Birthday!");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(600, 450);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 450);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new BdayCard();
}
}
```

Comment: As a general tip, it is better to do custom painting in a `JPanel` or other `JComponent`, then add that to a top level container such as a `JFrame`.  For custom painting in a `JComponent`, override `paintComponent(Graphics)` instead of `paint(Graphics)` and immediately call the `super` method to paint the BG and borders etc.

Comment: For question1: Use a boolean flag `if (shouldDraw) { g.fill... }`. Update the flag on the button press. Then again, you could also just use `setBackground()` for this particular case ;-)

Comment: @peeskillet I'm thinking this can be achieved without custom painting at all.  A call to `mainPanel.setBackground(color)` in the action listener should do the trick.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for the advice and solution.  I will ask about the layout in a different thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem with your blackscreen is because you paint at:

```
g.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 450);
```

you are using the default colour which is black
I tried your code and used this:

```
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
```

this clears your screen and then use a boolean and set it true when your button is pressed:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    button=true;
    repaint();
}
```

then finally use:

```
if(button){/*do stuff here*/}
```

in the paint method